# How can I configure DisplayFusion so that windows don't go under DisplayFusion taskbars when I maximize them?

Tags: windows-7, displayfusion

When I maximize a window, its bottom goes below the DisplayFusion taskbar. How can I configure DisplayFusion to prevent this from happening?

For example, I would like to have:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

(which happens when I maximize the window)

I use DisplayFusion Pro v5.0.1 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved in the newer versions of DisplayFusion (6.x and 7.x), just download a new version and it will work as expected.

http://www.displayfusion.com/Download/